# Mongo DB nested fields groupby not working

Tags: java, mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have nested fields in my db , in which I apply unwind and then groupby, to select all the fields using $first, but unfortunatley , I get an error of . not supported in transactionDetails

Can you check and tell me what is wrong in this pipeline:

```
{ $unwind : "$transactionDetails"} ,
    { $unwind : "$cardDetails"} ,
    { $unwind : "$merchantDetails"} ,
    { $unwind : "$transactionIdentifiers"} ,

{
   "$group":{
      "_id":{
         "accountNumber":"$accountNumber"
      },
      "transactionDetails.localDateTime":{
         "$first":"$transactionDetails.localDateTime"
      },
      "transactionDetails.sign":{
         "$first":"$transactionDetails.sign"
      },
      "cardDetails.cardProxy":{
         "$first":"$cardDetails.cardProxy"
      },
      "cardDetails.cardNumber":{
         "$first":"$cardDetails.cardNumber"
      },
      "accountNumber":{
         "$first":"$accountNumber"
      },
      "merchantDetails.name":{
         "$first":"$merchantDetails.name"
      },
      "postedAmount":{
         "$first":"$postedAmount"
      },
      "merchantDetails.cardAcceptorId":{
         "$first":"$merchantDetails.cardAcceptorId"
      },
      "merchantDetails.zipCode":{
         "$first":"$merchantDetails.zipCode"
      },
      "merchantDetails.city":{
         "$first":"$merchantDetails.city"
      },
      "transactionDetails.localCurrency":{
         "$first":"$transactionDetails.localCurrency"
      },
      "transactionDetails.transactionAmount":{
         "$first":"$transactionDetails.transactionAmount"
      },
      "transactionIdentifiers.retrievalReferenceNumber":{
         "$first":"$transactionIdentifiers.retrievalReferenceNumber"
      },
      "transactionIdentifiers.approvalCode":{
         "$first":"$transactionIdentifiers.approvalCode"
      }
   }
}
```

In the db table I am trying to select nested fields and it is not working as expected.

Comment: Would be great if you can share some sample data and your current aggregation through [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) :)

Comment: The error is not the collection structure and all , when I try to load the data using MongoSpark in the form of aggregated pipeline, it says MongoCommand error : fieldName: transactionDetails.localDateTime cannot contain (.) in between names, even after applying the $unwind